# Directory tree listing

Tags: php, ftp, dir

**Hi i am looking for script witch lists directory's from ftp and read's all files from the listed folder..Is there something that can help me?**

1. >   //open the dir

> $sub = ($_GET['dir']);
>                 $path = 'store/'.$diro.'/';
>                 $path = $path . "$sub";
>                 $dh = opendir($path);
>                 $i=1;
>                 while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
>                     if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
>                             if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
>                             echo "$i. $file 
> ";
>                             }else{
>                         echo "$i. $file";
>                           }
>                         $i++;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 closedir($dh);

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far?

Comment: PHP has an FTP extension which you can read about here: http://php.net/ftp. Otherwise, can you narrow down your question more? What things have you already tried? Why haven't they worked?

Comment: I have tried this but for some reason this do not work :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick Google, and there a [MILLIONS](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+retrieve+FTP+folder+listing) of responses to this question.

The fourth result is a complete code sample.

http://www.phpreg.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=158&Itemid=28

Something like....

```
<?php
     $connect = ftp_connect("ftp.hostname.com");
     $result = ftp_login($connect, "username", "password");
     $a = ftp_nlist($connect, "code22");
     foreach($a as $value){
         echo $value, "<BR>";
     }
?>
```

Comment: //open the dir
   
     
       $sub = ($_GET['dir']);
    $path = 'store/'.$diro.'/';
    $path = $path . "$sub";
    $dh = opendir($path);
    $i=1;
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
                echo "$i. $file <br />";
                }else{           
            echo "$i. <a href='?dir=$sub/$file'>$file</a><br />";
              }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);